# Fazer busca em uma matriz(lista de lista)

Tags: python, lista

Escrever uma função chamada `busca` que receba uma matriz (cada linha da matriz tem quatro entradas, representando as informações referentes a nome, registro, setor e telefone) e faça uma busca por setor. Essa função deve retornar o nome, o registro e o telefone dos funcionários daquele setor.

```
def busca(setor):
    matriz = [["Adalberto Ferreira", "566", "Contabilidade", "(21)84564-5248"],
              ["Juliana Vasconcelos", "465", "RH", "(21)3555-4552"],
              ["Flavia Amorim", "565", "Contabilidade", "(21)2134-4845"]]
    nome = matriz[0][0], matriz[1][0], matriz[2][0]
    registro = matriz[0][1], matriz[1][1], matriz[2][1]
    setor = matriz[0][2], matriz[1][2], matriz[2][2]
    telefone = matriz[0][3], matriz[1][3], matriz[2][3]
    if setor == matriz[1][3]:
        return [nome[1][0], registro[1][1], telefone[1][3]]
    else:
        return [[nome[0][0], registro[0][1], telefone[0][3]], [nome[2][0], registro[2][1], 
                telefone[2][3]]]
```

Eu cheguei a esse código mas ele apenas retorna uma parte da string, não a string completa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não faça a busca usando índices fixos. E se a matriz tiver mais que 3 registros? E se tiver menos?

Em vez disso, faça um *loop* pela matriz e guarde os funcionários do setor em uma lista:

```
def busca(setor_busca):
    matriz = [["Adalberto Ferreira", "566", "Contabilidade", "(21)84564-5248"],
              ["Juliana Vasconcelos", "465", "RH", "(21)3555-4552"],
              ["Flavia Amorim", "565", "Contabilidade", "(21)2134-4845"]]
    dados = []
    for nome, registro, setor, fone in matriz:
        if setor == setor_busca:
             dados.append([nome, registro, fone])
    return dados 

print(busca('Contabilidade'))
```

Repare que no `for` eu já posso atribuir cada elemento das sub-listas em variáveis, o que facilita na hora de manipulá-las.

Há outros problemas no seu código: você sobrescreve o valor do parâmetro `setor`, e no `return` você está na verdade pegando um único caractere de cada string.

---

Se quiser, também pode fazer com [*list comprehension*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), bem mais sucinta e [*pythônica*](/q/192343/112052):

```
def busca(setor_busca):
    matriz = [["Adalberto Ferreira", "566", "Contabilidade", "(21)84564-5248"],
              ["Juliana Vasconcelos", "465", "RH", "(21)3555-4552"],
              ["Flavia Amorim", "565", "Contabilidade", "(21)2134-4845"]]
    return [  [nome, registro, fone] for nome, registro, setor, fone in matriz  if setor == setor_busca]
```

---

Outro detalhe é que a matriz com todos os dados poderia ser criada fora da função e passada como parâmetro, assim a função fica mais genérica e funciona para quaisquer outros dados:

```
def busca(matriz, setor_busca):
    return [  [nome, registro, fone] for nome, registro, setor, fone in matriz  if setor == setor_busca]

matriz = [["Adalberto Ferreira", "566", "Contabilidade", "(21)84564-5248"],
              ["Juliana Vasconcelos", "465", "RH", "(21)3555-4552"],
              ["Flavia Amorim", "565", "Contabilidade", "(21)2134-4845"]]
print(busca(matriz, 'Contabilidade'))

# posso reusar a função para outra matriz 
outra_matriz = # outra matriz com dados diferentes 
print(busca(outra_matriz, 'outro setor'))
```

Answer (score -2):

Apenas para exemplificar, eu peguei a mesma matriz e separei apenas os nomes de cada perfil, pelo visto, eu também não sabia, mas quando você abre o segundo colchete para acessar o elemento da matriz o interpretador como se você tivesse fazendo fatiamento já que você está trabalhando com strings, então o correto é indicar que é pra pegar a string inteira, usando dois pontos`(:)`. Eu rodei o seu código e acho que você ainda não vai ficar satisfeito com o resultado, mas esse é o problema.

```
if setor == matriz[1][3]:
        return [nome[1][0:], registro[1][1:], telefone[1][3:]]
    else:
        return [[nome[0][0:], registro[0][1:], telefone[0][3:]], [nome[2][0:], registro[2][1:], 
                telefone[2:][3:]]]
```